# c++: Can I put the same object into a collection twice?

Tags: c++, collections, dynamic-memory-allocation

For example, I'm using the command pattern and adding commands to a queue.  The entries in the queue are CommandItems which is like a simple struct that holds the command object and the time to execute the command.

```
struct CommandItem
{
  time_t theTime;
  std::shared_ptr<Command> command;
  ...
  // comparison operator implemented
}

std::priority_queue<CommandItem> commandQueue_;
```

If I want to execute the same command twice at different times, such that there would be two CommandItems for the command in the queue, do I need to construct two separate command objects?  Or can I just put the same command object in twice? Pros/cons?

(Note using shared_ptr to command objects.  The queue needs to hold command objects of various subclasses)

Answer (score 3):

That's kind of the whole point of a `shared_ptr`, you can have multiple pointers to the same object and the object will be automatically deleted when nobody needs it anymore.

Since your Command class has subclasses, make sure it has a virtual destructor.

Comment: Makes sense, I guess it just feels weird to re-use an object like this, I'm used to creating new objects for each new use.  I'm wondering if later on if I modify the Command classes (not sure if it's reasonable to expect them to ever have state) whether this will come back to bite me.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your implementation, but generally I'd suggest creating separate objects for separate instances of action (even if its the same action).

Since its a pointer, it would then be a distinct instance in the collection (even though some collections allow multiple instances of the same item).